# Why does this code generate random duplicates?

Tags: loops, dataframe, pyspark

Let me start by saying I'm new to python/pyspark

I've got a dataframe of 100 items, I'm slicing that up into batches of 25 then for each batch I need to do work on each row.  I'm getting duplicate values in the last do work step.  I've verified my original list does not contain duplicates, my slice step generates 4 distinct lists

```py
batchsize = 25
sliced = []
emailLog = []
for i in range(1,bc_df.count(),batchsize):
  sliced.append({"slice":bc_df.filter(bc_df.Index >= i).limit(batchsize).rdd.collect()})
for s in sliced:
  for r in s['slice']:
    emailLog.append({"email":r['emailAddress']})


re = sc.parallelize(emailLog)
re_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(re)
re_df.createOrReplaceTempView('email_logView')    

%sql
select  count(distinct(email)) from email_logView
```

My expectation is to have 100 distinct email addresses, I sometiems get 75, 52, 96, 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by this line because it is not deterministic and allows duplicates:

```py
sliced.append({"slice":bc_df.filter(bc_df.Index >= i).limit(batchsize).rdd.collect()})
```

Let's take a closer look at what is happening (I assume that the index column ranges from 1 to 100).

Your range function generates four values for `i` (1,26,51 and 76).

- During the first iteration you request all rows which index is 1 or greater (i.e. [1,100]) and take 25 of them.
- During the second iteration you request all rows which index is 26 or greater (i.e. [26,100]) and take 25 of them.

  - During the third iteration you request all rows which index is 51 or greater (i.e. [51,100]) and take 25 of them.
- During the fourth iteration you request all rows which index is 76 or greater (i.e. [76,100]) and take 25 of them.

You already see that the intervals are overlapping. That means that the email addresses of an iteration could also have been taken by previous iterations.

You can fix this by simply extending your filter with an upper limit. For example:

```py
sliced.append({"slice":bc_df.filter((bc_df.Index >= i) & (bc_df.Index < i + batchsize)).rdd.collect()})
```

That is just a quick fix to solve your problem. As general advise I recommend you to avoid `.collect()` as often as possible because it does not scale horizontaly.

Comment: Thanks have not tried your fix but it does make sense.  I was assuming the list to be ordered which was wrong.   I ended up doing a modulo operation which also allowed me to get rid of the nested loops  - example:if tick % batchsize == 0:, and at the end sweep up remaining items